# Java Bucket Sort of Objects

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to write a bucket sort and my plan is to write a simple Entry class and another class with a main method and try to manipulate an array of lists.

My Entry Class (Class Node):

```
public class Node {

    protected int element;
    protected Node next;

    public Node()
    {
        element = 0;
        next = null;
    }
    public Node getNext(Node n)
    {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node n)
    {
        n = next;
    }
    public void setElement(int e)
    {
        e = element;
    }
    public int getElement()
    {
        return element;
    }
    public void insert(int e)
    {
        e = element;

    }
}
```

My Bucket Sort Class:

```
public class BucketSort extends Node {

    public void remove(int[] x)
    {
        x = null;
    }
    public static void bucketSort(int[] a)
    {
        int[] array = a;
        Node[] buckets = new Node[array.length];

        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            buckets[i] = null; 
        } 
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            array.remove(array[i]);
            buckets[i].insert(array[i]);
        }


    }

}
```

I do get an error at array.remove(array[i]); as well.

Comment: whats the error?  Show us the stack trace please

Comment: Down voted because the author removed the question and made the whole thread a discussion of something we cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.  When you declare the Node[] buckets its already empty there is no need to null it out.  Also BucketSort should not Extend Node, It should contain a collection of Node objects (Array for instance).  Your remove method should not accept an int[] but merely an int that will point to the index that is to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my quick observations of the design:

1. Have two different classes: `Node` which just represents the single node (`element` and `next`) and another class `LinkedList` which contains the head of the list. Now you can support methods like `add`, `remove`,`search` on the `LinkedList` class.
2. `BucketSort` extending `Node` isn't
   a good class design. You probably
   want to keep them independent and
   make BucketSort generic enough to sort on any data type. Keep the Sorting mechanism in a separate class and pass the LinkedList to it.
3. Why are `element` and `next` protected? You can change them to `Private`.
4. Since you are designing a LinkedList API, it would be better and cleaner to stick to the standard methods [LinkedList](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) supports.

Answer (score 0):

ok, two errors:

1 - array.remove(array[i]); ??? what is this? array does not have a method remove and you dont want do remove the item from array, do you? I think you can do just remove this line.

2 - If you create a bucket for each element in a array how this is a Bucket Sort? You should create less buckets than elements (grouping they in some way) right?